# Failed to convert mbr to gpt using gdisk

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, conversion, mbr, gpt

I urgently needed to install new windows and because of that I converted MBR to GPT using gdisk by following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-JyJQvyFpf8&ab_channel=f%26D). After that my hdd resulted into invalid dynamic and was able to recovery 3 partition out of 6 using testdisk by following steps from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pqt8_ktNkiw&ab_channel=Techniqued).
Any help about what recovery software to use or any other method would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have 6 partitions already it sounds like you are already are using GPT

Comment: thx for reply but when i tried to install new copy of windows 10 it said Windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk has an MBR partition table So i tried to convert mbr to gpt and it failed using gdisk

Comment: If you already had Windows 10 installed you should have used MBR2GPT but that only works if you have less than 3 partitions.  In fact any tool that converts MBR to GPT will have that requirement

Comment: yes i realized this afterward but it was too late and tried to convert GPT2MBR again and it did nothing so i again retrieve to GPT invalid state

Comment: and then tried testdisk to recover from backup option luckily 74% of 1Tb was recovered.